# Oracle Query in Codeigniter giving ORA-01722 and ORA-01756

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im usually use mysql database in my website, but i trying to learn more about the oracle...
My code working 2days ago, but right now its giving an error message such as **ORA-number**
this is my database fields

```
KODE_GUDANG CHAR        
GUDANG      CHAR
LASTUPDATE  CHAR            
KODE_UNIT   CHAR            
NOMER_REKJURNAL CHAR            
KODE_GUDANG_KREDIT  CHAR
```

this is my models for query

```
function getDataOneColumn($getCol, $table, $column, $id) {
    return $this->db->query("SELECT $getCol as val FROM $table WHERE $column = $id")->row_array();
  }
```

This is for my controller that giving an error : **ORA-01722**

```
 $this->data['no_rek'] = ($this->data['no_rek'] =='')?$this->m_dao->getDataOneColumn("NOMER_REKJURNAL","TBL_MASTER_GUDANG","KODE_GUDANG",$this->data['kode_gdg'])['VAL']:$this->data['no_rek'];
```

and after that i reading the docummentation, its means "*You executed a SQL statement that tried to convert a string to a number*"

i try to change my code to

```
 $this->data['no_rek'] = ($this->data['no_rek'] =='')?$this->m_dao->getDataOneColumn("NOMER_REKJURNAL","TBL_MASTER_GUDANG","KODE_GUDANG",'"'.$this->data['kode_gdg'])['VAL'].'"':"'".$this->data['no_rek']."'";
```

this one giving an other ORA error,**ORA-01756**. its means "*You tried to execute a statement that contained a string that was not surrounded by two single quotes*"

New Error

```
Error Number: 1722

ORA-01722: invalid number

SELECT NOMER_REKJURNAL as val FROM TBL_MASTER_GUDANG WHERE KODE_GUDANG = 04

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/formula/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Can somebody tell me why my code getting an error after 2days ?
And
How to solve this error?
thank you

Comment: I don't know  `codeigniter`, but what is the `id` value you are trying to pass ?

Comment: ignore the function, its for call my tabledata, and its work, what make it error is displaying @Sujitmohanty30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading lot of post with ORA error, I can solve my problem.
I just need adding **" ' ".$val." ' "**

```
 $this->data['no_rek'] = ($this->data['no_rek'] =='')?$this->m_dao->getDataOneColumn("NOMER_REKJURNAL","TBL_MASTER_GUDANG","KODE_GUDANG","'".$this->data['kode_gdg']."'")['VAL']:$this->data['no_rek'];
```